# Drawing MATLAB plots in Latex

Tags: graphics, elsarticle

I have some 2D and 3D figures in MATLAB. Below are two samples of the same kind-

[image]

and

[image]

How to include these figures in LaTeX? Till now I am including the exported PNG image but that doesn't look smooth while the document is zoomed in.

Comment: You could plot them in [pgfplots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf). Also there's `matlab2tikz`, which I never get to know.

Comment: Have you had a look at [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig)? It's very powerful, you can save in many different formats including pdf and png, set the resolution manually, use transparent background, etc.

Comment: The second one is immediate. The first one needs a csv or text file with the arrays as columns.

Comment: I generally save the image as an eps file or save the data as a csv file and read it in to pgfplots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Matlab2TikZ](https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz). This uses TikZ to generate the figures at compile-time.

On the matlab side, you use code like this:

```
matlab2tikz( '/PATH/FILE.tikz','height','\figureheight','width','\figurewidth',...
'extraAxisOptions',{'tick label style={font=\footnotesize}'}, ...
'extraAxisOptions',{'y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=2, /tikz/.cd}'});
```

And on the LaTeX side, code like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\setlength\figureheight{8cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{0.8\textwidth}
\input{PATH/FILE.tikz}
\caption{Caption Text.}
\label{fig:figureLabel}
```

\end{figure}

Here's an example (a `loglog` plot with legend, annotations and individual symbols).

[image: A loglog plot from Matlab with legend and individual symbols and annotations]

Answer (score 9):

While many find the `matlab2tikz` results satisfactory, I like the opportunity to use my own macros in the plots, so that if my notation changes, the entire document including plots will update itself. In this way, I'm nearly always consistent in my work.

Writing the plots by hand using native [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) also produces cleaner, more easily-modifiable, and more compact code than the auto-generated methods. There's a bit of a learning curve, but I find the investment to learn is worth it.

I simply have MATLAB or any other number-crunching code output raw `.dat` files, and `pgfplots` reads data from those. So if I re-run my code and then re-compile my document, the results are automatically updated.

I didn't have your scatter data, so I've created some "dummy data" using functions and random numbers for the first plot. I commented each option so you can see where each element of the plot comes from. The [`pgfplots` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) is some of the best in the business, and you can find further details for all options there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  only marks,                    % no lines
  xmin=0, xmax=200,              % x-axis limits
  ymin=0, ymax=300,              % y-axis limits
  xlabel={Dissimilarities},      % x-axis label
  ylabel={Distances},            % y-axis label
  title={Morse Signal Analysis}, % plot title
  legend pos=north west,         % legend position on plot
  legend cell align=left,        % text alignment within legend
  domain=20:180,                 % domain for plotted functions (not needed for scatter data)
  samples=200,                   % plot 200 samples
]
  \addplot[mark=o,blue] {x^2/200 + rand*x/3}; % add the first plot
  \addlegendentry{Stress}; % add the first plot's legend entry
  \addplot[mark=+,red]  {x^2/200 + rand*x/2}; % ...
  \addlegendentry{Sammon Mapping};
  \addplot[mark=triangle,green] {x^2/200 + rand*x/1.5};
  \addlegendentry{Squared Stress};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  grid=major,              % draw major gridlines
  major grid style=dotted, % dotted grid lines
  colormap/jet,            % colormap from MATLAB
  samples=30,              % 30 samples in each direction
  view={140}{30},          % configure plot view
  domain=-3:3,             % x varies from -3 to 3
  y domain=-3:3,           % y varies from -3 to 3
  zmin=-10, zmax=10,       % z-axis limits
  xlabel={$x$},            % x-axis label
  xtick={-3,-2,...,3},     % integer-spaced tick marks on the x-axis
  ylabel={$y$},            % y-axis label
  title={$y^2 - x^2$},     % plot title
]
  \addplot3[mesh] {y^2-x^2}; % make the mesh plot
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The question was specific on MATLAB plots, however, I agree with you that using PGF is the more general solution. At my university, folks first learn to use matlab and then, out of necessity, start to use latex. In that setting, matlab2tikz is the natural choice, since you don't have to learn more tex & co. than necessary. Students are quite reluctant to embrace latex, especially at the beginning.

Comment: @DohnJoe, I know the question asked about MATLAB plots specifically, this is the reason for the first 3 paragraphs of my answer. IMHO, the fact that "you don't have to learn more TeX & co. than necessary" is one of the major flaws of `matlab2tikz`. Everything works jolly good until something doesn't look as the user wants. Then he/she has to dig through a mess of paths and other code and change things in (potentially) hundreds of places, rather than just making a setting/style one time using `pgf`/TikZ/`pgfplots` from the start.

Comment: +1 For this great post. I find LaTeX very awesome but never got good working code examples for tikz. Thank you for sharing! This will be very useful in future projects :). Just a last quick question. How can I export the figure as an eps file, because compiling a file gets very slow if I always recompile the whole tikz code.